# How to manually merge all the /res values.xml?

Tags: java, android, delphi, android-resources, r.java-file

I need to build myself the r.class (via Aapt.exe). For this i must first "merge" all the res files of all the libraries. For exemple the **appcompat-v7** contain theses res :

```
res\values\values.xml
res\values-fr\values-fr.xml
```

and the **google play services** contain theses res :

```
res\values\values.xml
res\values-fr\values.xml
```

so i manually merge these files like this :

```
res\values\values.xml 
res\values-fr\values-fr.xml
res\values-fr\values.xml
```

but this not work, and google play service raise an error : `Requesting resource 0x7f05002b failed because it is complex`

but if i rename `res\values-fr\values-fr.xml` of **appcompat-v7** to `res\values-fr\values.xml` and then launch again the merging process to have :

```
res\values\values.xml 
res\values-fr\values.xml
```

then it's work !

so what is the exact rule to follow to merge all the res xml ? i m not under android studio, this why i need to merge the file by myself

Comment: Whether or not you use Android Studio you can still *use Gradle with the Android plugin on any platform.* Why would you try to do this yourself?

Comment: Thanks David, so let say i have play-services-base-10.2.1.aar and appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar ... how do you merge their resources with Gradle ?

Comment: Just set up your project to use Gradle with the Android plugin. Then declare those 2 libraries as dependencies and Gradle will do the rest. And I **highly** recommend you take the time and switch to Android Studio, too

Comment: i m under Delphi (similar to visual studio c++) and their is no Gradle option with Delphi. is their a way to install and configure myself Gradle ? this deserve to be the answer if you know how to do

Comment: What parameters do you pass to aapt? Which files do you merge exactly? You first mention 4 different files and then you merge only three. And at last you say that merging two files works? What happened to those extra files. Your steps are not clear enough.

Comment: I suggest you use Android Studio, create empty application add your dependencies and merge resources there. That is the simplest solution. If you want to use Gradle independently then go to https://gradle.org/